# Git clone error: OpenSSL SSL_read decryption failure

Tags: windows, git, github, ssl, openssl

I'm facing an issue while trying to clone a Git repository using the following command on my Windows machine:
`git clone https://github.com/balakrishnasajja/portfolio.git`

I received the following error message:

```
Cloning into 'portfolio'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 950, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (142/142), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (71/71), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: OpenSSL/1.1.1t: error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0
error: 5451 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

I'm not sure what's causing this issue. Here's some additional information:

1. I'm using Git version `git version 2.40.0.windows.1`
2. My operating system is Windows 11.

I've already tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

- Checked my internet connection and firewall settings.
- Updated Git to the latest version.
- Rebooted my computer.

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!